# NDSolve and vectors

Tags: differential-equations, vector, physics, vector-calculus

I think I can't find solution of  equation below because I need use scalars, not vectors as I have tried. But I don't know how I can do express the problem with scalars. I have read *Wolfram Language Tutorial* but did not find what I need. Please help me to understand how I can be done and how to fix my mistakes.

Also for example I used first boundary condition to see how it works.

I have another task.

I need to solve the equation in reference to m=m(t) for period {t,0,50}:

[image]

[image]

Code

```
γ = 28;
Subscript[μ, 0] = 1.25*10^-6;
Subscript[μ, 0]*Subscript[M, 0] == 800*10^-3;
Subscript[B, dc] = 200*10^-3;
Subscript[B, eff] = {Subscript[B, dc], 0, 0} - 
  Subscript[μ, 0]*Subscript[M, 0] Dot[m, {0, 0, 1}]
Subscript[α, G] = 0.01;
Subscript[I, dc] = 1*10^-3;
e = 1.602*10^-19;
\[ScriptH] = 6.582*10^-16;
Subscript[r, 0] = 100*10^-9;
Subscript[l, 0] = 3*10^-9;
p = {0, 0, 1};
σ = (γ*\[ScriptH]/(2*e))*(1/(Subscript[M, 0]*3.14*
      Subscript[r, 0]^2*Subscript[l, 0]))
vec1 == Cross[Subscript[B, eff], m[t]];
vec2 == Cross[m[t], D[m[t]]];
vec3 == Cross[m[t], p];
vec4 == Cross[m[t], vec3];
m[t] == {mx[t], my[t], mz[t]};
time = {t, 0, 50};

system = {D[m[t], t] == γ*vec1 + 
     Subscript[α, G]*vec2 + σ*Subscript[I, dc]*vec4, 
   m[0] == {1, 0, 0}};
NDSolve[system, m[t], time]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulties here are due exclusively to syntax errors, such as interchanging `Set` and `Equal`.  If the code is rewritten as,

```
γ = 28;
Subscript[μ, 0] = 1.25*10^-6;
Subscript[M, 0] = 800*10^-3/Subscript[μ, 0];
Subscript[B, dc] = 200*10^-3;
Subscript[B, eff] = {Subscript[B, dc], 0, 0} - 
                Subscript[μ, 0]*Subscript[M, 0] Dot[m[t], {0, 0, 1}];
Subscript[α, G] = 0.01;
Subscript[I, dc] = 1*10^-3;
e = 1.602*10^-19;
 = 6.582*10^-16;
Subscript[r, 0] = 100*10^-9;
Subscript[l, 0] = 3*10^-9;
p = {0, 0, 1};
σ = (γ*/(2*e))*(1/(Subscript[M, 0]*3.14*Subscript[r, 0]^2*Subscript[l, 0]));
vec1 = Cross[Subscript[B, eff], m[t]];
vec2 = Cross[m[t], D[m[t]]];
vec3 = Cross[m[t], p];
vec4 = Cross[m[t], vec3];
m[t] = {mx[t], my[t], mz[t]};
time = {t, 0, 50};

system = {D[m[t], t] == γ*vec1 + Subscript[α, G]*vec2 + σ*Subscript[I, dc]*vec4, 
    (m[t] /. t -> 0) == {1, 0, 0}};
s = Flatten@NDSolve[system, m[t], {t, 0, 10^-17}];
```

With these changes, the code produces the results below

```
Plot[Evaluate[ {mx[t], my[t], mz[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 10^-17}, AxesLabel -> {t, m}]
```

[image]

A very short time period is used, because the equations reach steady-state very quickly.  By the way, using `Subscript` variables invites errors.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But i have message about mistake  "There are fewer dependent variables, {mx[t],my[t]}, than equations, \
so the system is overdetermined"

Comment: @John  There was a transcription error in my answer, now corrected.  However, it would not have created the error you quoted.  I suggest you restart Mathematica, copy the code from my answer, and run it.